# How do you capture console output under debug in clion?

Tags: c++, clion

I'm using clion to write a console application. If I simply run the program, I can see the results of my `cout` calls. But if I debug it, no output occurs under the Debug Console tab other than my exe's name and `Process finished with exit code 0`. Is there an extra step to get console output to show up under debug in clion?

Or is this not even clion specific and is a general thing people who have been using gdb already know about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [JetBrains'post on clion debugger](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2015/05/debug-clion/), you can see the debug output by click the "Console" tab, which is next to "Debugger" tab:

[image]

Comment: Haven't been using clion much since this question is posted, so I assume a) they added this in a newer version and b) your post is correct. As such, you get the prize. :D

Comment: Thanks :) I have the same question, google it, and find the answer. Really surprised to see that no one has answered this question before.

Answer (score -3):

GDB manipulates the process of running a program.

An example of GDB session:

```
% cat hello.c
#include<stdio.h>

main() {
    int count;

    for (count=0;count<10;count++)
       printf("Hello from CETS!\n");
}

% gcc -g hello.c
% gdb ./a.out
GDB is free software and you are welcome to distribute copies of it
 under certain conditions; type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB; type "show warranty" for details.
GDB 4.13 (sparc-sun-solaris2.3), 
Copyright 1994 Free Software Foundation, Inc...
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x10784: file hello.c, line 6.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home1/b/bozo/./a.out 


Breakpoint 1, main () at hello.c:6
6           for (count=0;count<10;count++)
(gdb) s
7              printf("Hello from CETS!\n");
(gdb) p count
$1 = 0
(gdb) disp count
1: count = 0
(gdb) set count=8
(gdb) s
Hello from CETS!
6           for (count=0;count<10;count++)
1: count = 8
(gdb) 
7              printf("Hello from CETS!\n");
1: count = 9
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Hello from CETS!

Program exited with code 01.
(gdb) q
%
```

Content that might be helpful for you:

http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/howto_gdb.html

http://www.ifp.illinois.edu/~nakazato/tips/xgcc.html#GDB

http://www.seas.upenn.edu/cets/answers/gcc.html

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really see how that answers the question. You don't interact directly with gdb when you're using clion. It's an IDE.

Comment: That's okay, just making sure I'm not missing something or wasn't clear enough in my question.